# Как создать условие для Collectors Java Stream API (для преобразования InputStream в String)?

Tags: java, java-8

Есть метод

```
public String convert(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {
            return br.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
        }
    }
```

Как создать условие "если строка пустая, остановить чтение из InputStream"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
br.lines()
  .takeWhile(Predicate.not(String::isEmpty))
  .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
```

Comment: нет такого метода takeWhile, как так?

Comment: Метод `takeWhile` появился в Java 9. Без него останется только писать свой коллектор.